# Not sure how to display this object property in my react app

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

[image: This is the object showing up in the console. I have to fetch the circled property and display it in my react app.]

I tried console.log(response.sql.sql) but it's returning the following error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'sql' of undefined.

Following is the JSON.stringify of this same object-

```
 {

   "sql":{

      "external":false,
      "sql":[

],
      "timeDimensionAlias":"line_items__created_at_day",
      "timeDimensionField":"LineItems.createdAt",
      "order":{

},
      "cacheKeyQueries":{

},
      "preAggregations":[

],
      "dataSource":"default",
      "aliasNameToMember":{

},
      "rollupMatchResults":[

         
      ],
      "canUseTransformedQuery":{

}
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to do `console.log(response && response.sql && response.sql.sql)`? I am assuming the response takes a while so it is, at the beginning, `undefined`

Comment: is it possible to do the same with setTimeout? i am trying to implement setTimeout into my useEffect

Comment: I think it is possible, just be sure that the time is enough to allow `sql` to become defined

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the response takes a while so, at the beginning, `sql` is `undefined`.

Try to do:

```
console.log(response && response.sql && response.sql.sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

try response.data.sql.sql
From my experience, anything in the response, on client-side can be read via response.data object